# Use external class in AngularJs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't quite follow how to inject external constructors, I have this constructor:

```
function myAudio(url){
    var song = new Audio();
    song.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    song.src = url;
    var source  = context.createMediaElementSource(song);
    source.connect(context.destination);

    this.play = function(){
        source.mediaElement.play();
    } 

}
```

outside, just with Javascript it works ok. I can create objects using `var myVar = new myAudio("some_url")`

I want to use that constructor inside an AngularJS controller but I just can't figure out how to do it.

I tried declaring it in the controller without success

```
app.controller("myAppCtrl", myMainFunction);
myMainFunction.$inject = ["$interval", "myAudio"];
function myMainFunction($interval, myAudio) {
   scope = this;
   //my controller stuff
}
```

Tried to make it return an object but I didn't find the correct way to do it.

I don't know what I am missing...

Comment: You register it as a service first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like that

```
app.factory('MyAudio', function() {
    function MyAudio(url){
        var song = new Audio();
        song.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        song.src = url;

        this.source = context.createMediaElementSource(song);
        this.source.connect(context.destination);
    }

    MyAudio.prototype.play = function(){
        this.source.mediaElement.play();
    };

    return MyAudio;
});

app.controller("myAppCtrl", myMainFunction);
myMainFunction.$inject = ["$interval", "MyAudio"];
function myMainFunction($interval, MyAudio) {
    this.myAudio = new MyAudio('/some/url.mp3');
    this.myAudio.play();
    // controller stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I just need to be sure that I delete the object every time I need to change the URL

Answer (score 0):

Register your class as a service like you have registered your controller.

```
app.service("myAudio", myAudio);
```

A good sum up about services and injection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17944367/652669

Answer (score 0):

A service is a singleton created by angular using a constructor definition (similar to `myAudio`). In order to inject the singleton service, you need to tell angular to instantiate it by using below definition:

```
app.service("myAudio", myAudio);

function myAudio(url){
  var song = new Audio();
  song.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  song.src = url;
  var source  = context.createMediaElementSource(song);
  source.connect(context.destination);

  this.play = function(){
      source.mediaElement.play();
  } 

}
```

Then you can inject it in your controller or other services. Refer https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services for more details

Comment: service returns a singleton and "url" will injected by DI and throws an exception